# Can progress be measured in a Shell sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Same question as title. Not a real problem I'm having or anything, I was just curious about this one.

Comment: In what way? This is a bit vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) animates the shell sort.  The code is available ,  it should give ideas on how to measure progress.

Comment: Simple and clever! I reckon it'd be especially useful for sets of big items - otherwise the animation would be make the sort time itself significantly slower.

Answer (score 2):

Since a shell sort has a specific [gap sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort#Gap_sequence) (and even an optimal one), your progress could be roughly indicated by whichever gap you're currently using. You're almost done when you hit the final insertion sort, as that will run in very-nearly-linear time to the size of the input.

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought but the same gap can be displayed for 45 seconds...

Comment: Sure, if you wanted something more concrete, you could also display _where_ in the gap the current pointers were located. It'd be a lot of motion which tends to impress people... :)

Answer (score 0):

The number of comparisons in a gap sort is fixed and can be calculated from the increment sequence and the input length. Thus the current gap and position in the input can be used to report a pretty accurate and linear progress.

Comment: But the amount of time each gap lasts is not lineal!

Comment: @vemv: That's why I said "current gap and position in the input"